# Dynamic configuration parameters via parse_ini_file()

Tags: php, configuration, ini

I have a snippet of configuration code that looks like this:

```
        $config = array(
            'layer one' => array(
                'host' => 'one.example.com',
                'prefix' => '',
                'isRemote' => false
            ),
            'layer two' => array(
                'host' => 'two.example.com',
                'prefix' => '/Example/two/public/index.php/',
                'isRemote' => true
            ),
            'layer three' => array(
                'host' => 'three.example.com',
                'prefix' => '/Example/three/public/index.php/',
                'isRemote' => true
            )
        );
```

I'm trying to migrate this configuration to an .ini file. The problem is, there can be an arbitrary number of the "layers" listed above, but they all must have the same set of attributes: host, prefix, and isRemote.

What's the way to represent this in an .ini file loaded by `parse_ini_file()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend a YAML instead of INI.

Comment: @DaveChen That actually sounds reasonable. I have to look into it!

Comment: Try http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

Comment: If you decide to use this datatype, you may use [yaml_parse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php) in PHP.